# split audio file into parts but i need to use these files in speech recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition, google-speech-api, pydub

i am facing problem in google speech recognition about long audio file .. so i decided to split my audio file in 15 sec .. each time i send first 15 sec to speech recognition then the second 15 sec and so on ...

but now when i use pydub lib it split the audio file the return value after splitting is not a file extension since API need a file extension as parameter   (i marked the error)
it says  "Given audio file must be a filename string or a file-like object"

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import numpy

from os import path
AUDIO_FILE = "OAF_back_happy.wav"

from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("OAF_back_happy.wav")

halfway_point = len(sound) // 2
split = []
split.append(sound[:halfway_point])
split.append(sound[halfway_point:])
r = sr.Recognizer()

words=1
for x in split:
  with sr.AudioFile(x) as source:     #<-----
      audio = r.record(source)  # read the entire audio file
  try:
      # for testing purposes, we're just using the default API key
      # to use another API key, use `r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
      # instead of `r.recognize_google(audio)`
      ans = r.recognize_google(audio)
      print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " +ans)
      for x in ans:
        if (x.isspace()) == True: 
          words+=1
      print(words) 
  except sr.UnknownValueError:
      print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
  except sr.RequestError as e:
      print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

Edited : as described in comment i dont want to export files bec i am using server and i dont want to put same file "twice"

Comment: The [pydub docs](http://pydub.com/) say you can do `x.export(...)` to save each slice to a file that you can then pass to `sr.AudioFile(...)`. E.g., `x.export("slice.wav", format="wav")` then `with sr.AudioFile("slice.wav") as source:`

Comment: @JustinEzequiel yah i know about the export thing but i am working on a server so i cant just export these files on the server thats too much ..

Comment: Then you should have mentioned that before.

Comment: The docs also say that export also works with a file handle, e.g., a BytesIO instance. The other docs also say that sr.AudioFile also works with a BytesIO instance so there you go. Cannot be bothered to provide links to the docs as I am away from computer and am posting from my phone.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel thanks for helping me, i am not that professional in python but you meant editing that line like that `with sr.AudioFile(io.BytesIO(x)) as source:` ? if yes, its giving me that error " a bytes-like object is required, not 'list ", if no, when you are free can you please type it type it as code so i can understand more, i appreciate your help

Comment: Read again the first sentence of my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested as I cannot be bothered to install packages I do not use but here's what I mean.

```py
for x in split:
    b = io.BytesIO()
    x.export(b)
    b.seek(0)
    with sr.AudioFile(b) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)
```